# The meaning of free parameters

Tags: degrees-of-freedom

I read the following sentence:

> Θ is specified by k free parameters.

What does that mean? Does it mean that the dimension of Θ is k? Or anything else?
Thank you.

Comment: Could you please tell us the source? Can [this article](https://www.statisticshowto.com/free-parameter/#:~:text=A%20free%20parameter%20is%20one,parameters%20include%20fixed%20and%20constrained.) solve your problem?

Comment: where did you read it? What's the context??

Comment: Usually--regardless of context--it means $\Theta$ is locally a $k$-dimensional manifold.  The "locally" is there, and I haven't specified what kind of manifold (topological, differentiable, Riemannian, etc.), because those technical details vary with the setting.